# grub rescue fixing by installing new OS

Tags: linux, multi-boot, bootloader, ubuntu-18.04

Today I tried to uninstall linux which I installed alongside windows 7.For that I deleted the linux partition from disk management in windows 7.I followed this tutorial-

https://itsfoss.com/uninstall-ubuntu-linux-windows-dual-boot/

I was unaware of grub rescue error.So I just stopped till deleting Linux partition and restarted my PC.I am stuck at grub rescue screen.I found a fix that says by booting into new os I can fix that error, By using terminal.My question is that  will I get my old windows 7 and old data back?

Comment: Before trying anything else, *save your data*! Image the disk, so you can get it back when issues occur.

Comment: Will it work even after all this? and can I use external hard drive for imaging

Comment: You can use a boot USB drive, e.g. on made by Macrium Reflect on another PC, to create an image of the whole drive... all sectors. An external HDD is ideal for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must reinstall the Windows bootloader.
In your case, just follow your tutorial and do "Part 2: Fixing Windows boot loader". That is, if you have a Windows installation disk, choose "Repair your computer". In Advanced Options or System Recovery Options look for Command Prompt. Execute `bootrec.exe /fixmbr`.

Comment: Can I use windows 10 for that

Comment: Ok, I haven't done it this way. I would do if needed because the MBR is already damaged.